# Net Start SSHD HELPMSG 3534

Tags: git, cygwin, git-svn

I am trying to setup Git on a Windows box and so far all appears to be working ... except this:

`net start sshd` gets the error `NETHELPSMG 3534`

When I type

`cygrunsrv --start sshd` I get  `QueryServiceStatus: Win32 error 1062`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [find here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/95625) the steps taken to solve this issue under cygwin:

> - Look at /var/log/sshd.log:
>     `/var/empty` must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
> - Adjust mode of `/var/empty` and attempt to start `sshd`:

```
$ chmod 700 /var/empty
```

> - Change owner of /var/empty:

```
20080217-144416 Administrator <at> a64x23800p /var
$ chown root empty/
chown: invalid user: `root'
```

> - root is not a valid user name.  Make an educated guess and try again:

```
20080217-151048 Administrator <at> a64x23800p /var
$ chown SYSTEM empty

20080217-151056 Administrator <at> a64x23800p /var
$ ll -d empty/
drwx------+ 2 SYSTEM None 0 Feb 17 14:30 empty//
```

Then:

```
20080217-151108 Administrator <at> a64x23800p /var
$ net start sshd
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service was started successfully.
```

---

Regarding the 1062 error, it reports that the windows service has not been started.

```
$ cygrunsrv --start sshd
cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus: Win32
error 1062:
The service has not been started.

..

$ net start sshd
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started. # only if the previous section was not solved
```

Note: be aware that:

- some anti-virus might interfere with that service.
  See [this thread](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2007-11/msg00010.html).
- older version of `cygwin1.dll` might also interfere with the process.
  See [that thread](http://lists-archives.org/cygwin/20965-still-seeing-win32-error-1062-starting-sshd-with-cygrunsrv-s-with-openssh-4-5p1-1-suggestions-please.html).

Comment: Hi VonC, I was unable to issue the command `ll -d empty/`: `-bash: 11: command not found`.

Comment: My sshd.log also says the following `Unable to initialize device PRN`

Comment: @MatthewMoisen '`ll`' is an alias for '`ls -alrt`'